# Send SMS between Android emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sms

I can send sms to a emulator with "extended controls"->"phone"

[image]

and with command line :

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 emu sms send 5551234 Hello Android
```

but i can't send and receive sms with built-in sms application like this :

[image]

i use android studio 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall android studio and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Actually you make call or receive sms only from emulator extended controls.you cannot do them from your emulator.The number 5554 is device id it's not the device's phone number.